# UIWebView movies don't save where they were at streaming

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, stream, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

So I use a `UIWebView` to stream my embedded youtube video using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`.
This works great. However, I noticed that the `MPMoviePlayerController` keeps losing the already streamed frames. When I start the video, press "Done" and the restart the video again, it begins from the very beginning again. I first thought that this is the default behavior and checked it by loading a request with the url youtube.com and played a random video. The controller saved the stream.

So my question is whether I did something wrong or wether UIWebView doesn't save it's stream when loadHTMLString:baseURL: is used?

Comment: what do you mean by "my embedded youtube video" ? is it some local file ? what is the differenc ebetween your video and the other ones you tested ?

Comment: An embedded video is an attempt to make an UIWebView look like a native MPMoviePlayerController that plays a YouTube video. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview

Comment: It might help if you give us some code to look at...

Comment: I think you mean the buffer. Youtube videos don't stream.