# MPMoviePlayerController not playing video

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Here is my code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mcjR3TsK4s&feature=g-logo&context=G2e376ceFOAAAAAAAAAA"];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:mp.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mp];
[mp play];
```

So video shoul play when I starts the app but it is not playing. Can anybody see what is wrong in code?  I included MediaPlayer framework and import Mediaplayer.h
Thanks!

Comment: You can't just put a direct YouTube URL into a MPMoviePlayer. The URL you defined represents a web page, not video data.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII So how can i play YouTube URL?

Comment: You could use `[UIApplication openURL:youtubeURL]` which should launch the youtube.app that ships with your device, or you can do some fancy stuff to get a .mp4 link to the video itself. I can help you with some of that, just let me know.

Comment: Check out this link, if you have a server you can use t hat has PHP available. http://www.ngcoders.com/php/php-youtube-video-downloader-script

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII please help me with that stuff  "to get a .mp4 link to the video itself"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot play YouTube video via MPMoviePlayerController. Use UIWebView or default app with custom URL scheme for this aim

See also 
[Play YouTube videos with MPMoviePlayerController instead of UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview)