# Play YouTube videos in iPhone app without using UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play YouTube videos from my iPhone app. I have to tried play YouTube videos in my iPhone app with the following codes,

```
[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL2l_Q1AR_Q" frame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 280, 250)];

- (void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
    NSLog(@"%@",html);
}
```

But, this code is not working for me. And also i have tried with `MPMoviePlayerController` the code is,

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL2l_Q1AR_Q"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
[moviePlayerController play];
```

This is also not working for me. Can anyone please tell me where i did wrong and suggest me any ideas? I want to play the YouTube videos in `MPMoviewPlayerController` rather than using `UIWebView`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mr.Yuvaraj.M your above code is correct. Please run the project in your iPhone/iPod touch device. The youtube videos may not support/not work in Simulator. Please check on this. Thanks.

Comment: Mr.Gopinath thanks for your answer. I will check your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just use [XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController). It seamlessly adds youtube video to your app without the need of `UIWebView`.

It uses progressive download + `MoviePlayer` and `AVFoundation` frameworks. Just supply it with a youtube video ID and you are good to go.

It supports both full-screen & non full-screen and **WORKS ON iOS SIMULATOR!!!**

Example:

```
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

Comment: i add this library using pod, and which header i want to use for this.

Comment: @R.Mohan should be `#import <XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.h>`

Answer (score 8):

There is now a `YTPlayerView` class available with the [YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Have a look at [Using the YouTube Helper Library to embed YouTube videos in your iOS application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#adding_ytplayerview)

It gives comprehensive instructions on how to install the helper library, and incorporate YTPlayerView into your storyboard.

Comment: Lib uses `UIWebView` only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the HTML embed code you are using, go to the YouTube website, find a video, use the share button and then the Embed button to get some example Embed HTML.  Use that pattern for embedding the video rather than the Flash version you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

### Play youtube video in swift 4.1

Add Pod pod 'XCDYouTubeKit'

import XCDYouTubeKit in ViewController

```
func playYoutubeVideo(){

let strUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m_K2Yg7wGQ"
if let range = strUrl.range(of: "=") {
        let strIdentifier = strUrl.substring(from: range.upperBound)
        print("Identifier:\(strIdentifier)")
        let videoPlayerViewController = 
        XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController(videoIdentifier: strIdentifier)
        videoPlayerViewController.present(in: viewYTVideo)
        videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.play()
    }
}
```