# Using a web view to play videos only from youtube

Tags: ios

### [image]

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
      <html><head>\
      <style type=\"text/css\">\
      body {
      background-color: transparent;
      color: white;
      }
      </style>
      </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
      width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
      </body></html>";
```

**used this script to play videos and its working fine with iPhone but not with iPad. frame not get set.**

```
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, str_url];
[web_View loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[web_View scalesPageToFit];
web_View.scrollView.bounces=NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, there is need to reinvent the wheel now, you can use [YTPlayer](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) control for iOS. I am using it and it works fine. Even if you are stick with your solution it can help you on this issue.

Just one thing about `YTPlayer`, it does not support seek bar option.

[Other ready-made options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060153/play-youtube-videos-in-iphone-app-without-using-uiwebview)