# Does anyone know newpipe android project available for iOS or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, youtube, youtube-api

I want to play Youtube Video in my app. but i can not find android newpipe type library in iOS.

In android newpipe full project available for get Youtube Full Url but i can not find same library/project for iOS.

there is any library same as android newpipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play youtube video in ios then you can use

**[YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)**

or there are several library also available on github.

1) [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

2) [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit)

and 3rd and last option is you can open with the help of UIWebview.
For more detail check below SO question.

> 1)
>   [play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview)
>
> 2) [play-youtube-videos-in-iphone-app-without-using-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060153/play-youtube-videos-in-iphone-app-without-using-uiwebview)

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Currently i am using XCDYoutubeKit but in that i can't get Video url for some of the videos and i got error like 

"Video operation finished with error: This video contains content from UMG. It is restricted from playback on certain sites.",
"This video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube",
"This video contains content from VEVO. It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube"

Comment: XCDYoutubekit works fine but my some of video  not playing because of this types of  error.

Any other solution for this ?

Comment: yes for your error there is a solution on github . please check this link https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/196

Comment: there is a new commit for the error "This video contains content from UMG" check issue 231 https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/231

Comment: I have check that solution but still can't remove error.

Comment: see my last comment.

Comment: That's why i try to find other Library for get Youtube full url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104145/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-nimisha-ranipa).