# I'm unable to save or download video in document directory and play from document directory

Tags: ios, video, download, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to **download** or **save** **youtube video** in document directory and then **play** that video using **MPMoviePlayerViewController**. But I don't know why my code is not working.

I'm using this below code :

## prgrma mark- download Or save

```
-(IBAction)onclick_download:(id)sender
{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
        NSString *urlToDownload = @"youtubeurl";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            
            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"thefile.mp4"];
            
            //saving is done on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"File Saved !");
            });
        }
        
    });
    
}
```

## pragma mark- Play video from document directory

```
-(IBAction)onclick_playvideolocally:(id)sender
{
    [self playvideolocally];
}
-(void)playvideolocally
{
    NSURL *videoUrl;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
    
    NSString *fullpath;
    
    for ( NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
    {
        fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];
        videoUrl =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
    }
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: The MPMoviePlayerController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

Comment: You can't download youtube video directly from url and also its not app store safe.apple won't allow to download video from third party

Comment: @SunnyShah : Then what is the other option to download you tube video from URL?

Comment: Go to my answer @moni_BQ

Comment: Hope this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060153/play-youtube-videos-in-iphone-app-without-using-uiwebview

Comment: @MoinShirazi : let me try

Comment: If you are planning for app store release then its 95% of chance of your app rejection. So keep in mind

Comment: It means if i used `LBYouTubeExtractor ` then my app will not approved by apple?

Comment: Yes..... mine was approved

Comment: Yes LBYouTubeView most likely does violate apple guidelines. Use it on your own risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your link you provided in url is for youtube so it is not downloaded or saved in local

Use this for youtube

Ive used classes from this project: https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView It works fine for me. I can download youtube videos.

```
LBYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@"), self.videoID ]] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge] autorelease];
[extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        NSLog(@"Did extract video URL using completion block: %@", videoURL);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: videoURL];
            NSString *pathToDocs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"video_%@.mp4"), self.videoID ];
            [data writeToFile:[pathTODocs stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File %@ successfully saved", filename);
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:%@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: I get an error `Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:Error Domain=LBYouTubeExtractorErrorDomain Code=2 "Couldn't find the stream URL." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't find the stream URL.}
`