# Play Video from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have used this coding in `viewDidLoad` Method:-

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4-YdC5N6Lo"];
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 260)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

When I run the app, then a black screen show but not play video. I want to play video from url. Can anybody help me.

Comment: You want to play particularly *Youtube* video?

Comment: You cannot play *Youtube* video directly using `MPMoviePlayerController` You can test [this sample MP4 URL](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4)

Answer (score 3):

**MPMoviePlayerController** not playing youtube video directly, it play only video file path Url in ios, so try [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser).

for additional information see the [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060153/play-youtube-videos-in-iphone-app-without-using-uiwebview)

Answer (score 1):

`MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated in  *iOS10* you can now use `AVKit`

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```