# How to play video from URL in Ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my application i get the links of video from server in UITableview .all these link are store on Sever in Textfile,i get  all these link from sever one by one and assign each to cell in UITableview.all these i done succefully but i want when i click on any cell in UITableview its play the video in next view.here is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     nextview *dvController = [[nextview alloc] initWithNibName:@"nextview" bundle:nil];
     [self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
     strFile = [Listdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"test=%@",strFile);
     [dvController release];
  }
```

and in next view i assign the link which i store in "strFile" to MPMoviePlayerController here is my code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
 NSLog(@"mytest=%@",strFile);
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strFile];
 NSLog(@"myurl=%@",url);
 myplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
 myplayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,900, 700);  
 [self.view addSubview:myplayer.view];
 [myplayer play];
 }
```

In NSlog i see the link but its not play in MPMoviePlayerController.Any one can guide me that what mistake i make.thanx in advance.

Comment: Show us what `mytest` prints out for you, in the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: in nslog mytest show this mytest=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJSkmmUhpHs

Comment: Have you made sure that the video can be played by iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be setting the frame and adding to the subview, You may be confused with `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Try this...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 NSLog(@"mytest=%@",strFile);
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strFile];
 NSLog(@"myurl=%@",url);
 myplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
 myplayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
 [myplayer play];
 }
```

**EDIT** disregard my code, you can't directly play a YouTube video in MPMoviePlayerController. Check this Post instead [Play YouTube videos with MPMoviePlayerController instead of UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview)

Comment: Dear skram i use your code  nothing happen same result that no video play in my mpmovieplayer.

Comment: Thanx Ok i got your point but inside cell in uitableview i also have webview which show the thumbnail of that link which is store in that specific cell.can it possible to play video in nextview throught webview.

Comment: You can embed YouTube videos in a UIWebView, alternatively on the link that I posted there's an example doing so.

Answer (score 2):

@prince : can u tell me what url you are getting in NSLog?? i think u're mistaken in getting the url.

we can get url either by

`url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strUrl];`

else

`url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];`

try it out once.

Comment: i see this url in NSlong test=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJSkmmUhpHs
mytest=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJSkmmUhpHs
myurl=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJSkmmUhpHs

Answer (score 0):

to youtube video play inside app is to create a UIWebView with the embed tag from Youtube for the movie you want to play as the UIWebView's content. UIWebView will detect that the embedded object is a Youtube link, and the web view's content will be the youtube preview for the video. When your user clicks the preview, the video will be shown in an MPMoviePlayerController. try this link:

> `http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application`

Unfortunately, there's no way to directly play a youtube video with MPMoviePlayerController because youtube does not expose direct links to the video files.