# How to play youtube Videos With MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there any other way to play  youtube videos other than UIWebView.i want to play youtube videos in MPMOviePlayer.i have done research on it but i found  no result.i got this url

[Play YouTube videos with MPMoviePlayerController instead of UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview)

please help me in  doing this.thanks in advance

Comment: And what to the answer there state? `The only way to have a youtube video play inside your own app is to create a UIWebView with the embed tag from Youtube for the movie you want to play as the UIWebView's content.` So there is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys solution for this

https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

Comment: LBYouTubeView has been discontinued by author.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from github :
https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

It's great, but sometime it can't play few links, seem like it can't get real URL video,

```
NSDictionary *qualities = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:url];
_urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:[qualities objectForKey:@"medium"]];
```

just return nil for ***qualities***. Anybody have idea to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For me this solution es better and pretty simple but elegant and it did work perfectly

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser