# Force youtube video from UiView to play

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating an app which include youtube videos. For this app i need a way to force the youtube video to open. how can i force it to start?

i've looked at this:

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But cant seem to figure out how to use it.

This is the code:

```
stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", youtubeId[0]];
headerTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theTitle[0]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187577/how-to-open-youtube-video-in-mpmovieplayercontroller-and-play-it?rq=1) question.

Comment: since you're using a UIWebView here and not a UIView, I'm thinking your question is [*actually* a duplicate of this one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717754/objective-c-how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview).

Comment: are you want to play the youtube video in mpmovie player or want to open it in webview with embeded youtube url

Comment: here in code u r using webview but you are not using embeded ones url

Comment: i want to open it in full screen like when you click on the youtube video inside my webview. I think thats mpmovieplayer

Comment: for this you have to use youtube parser by which you can achive and then you will pass the parsed url to mpmoviewplayer to open it directly it is not possible bcz youtube does not allow.

Comment: wait i will gives you url which will help you in solving the problem

Comment: if you find problem let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will get working example project in which it is using HCYoutubeParser to parse the youtube url

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

form here you can down load working code and you can check it on simulator and iphone both
even it will explain how to use it.

Comment: just by looking at the comments of that repo.. i can tell that it's a very non-stable solution