# how can i Play youtube video in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube, video-player

I want to play youtube videos in my iOS App,I saw that there are many options like embedding video and all in `UIWebview`.But i want it like a player.When i click the button then it opens new page and the video should play .

I even searched in google then i heard about this control

"XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController-master"  When i integrate this to my project

like

inside my `youtube.m` file

in `viewdidAppear()` i have added this code

```
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

and then it opening a video player and within seconds the video player closing .Its not playing anything.

When i tried to embed video

```
 webView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%@",sharedManager.trailerLink);
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharedManager.trailerLink]]];
```

am getting a window like youtube mobile site please check image.i want only one video in my screen .
[image]
Please help me

Comment: may this url help you where you will get youtube parser and you will sample code and explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914360/force-youtube-video-from-uiview-to-play/20920680#20920680

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to load a youtube video with the same controls as a `MPMoviePlayer`-object, but you can skip loading the related content by using [YouTubes iFrame-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

To load videos in a UIWebview, use this helper:

```
- (NSString*)youTubeHTMLFromURL:(NSURL*)url
{
  NSError *error = NULL;
  NSRegularExpression *regex =
  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=v(=|/))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|(?<=youtu.be/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"
                                            options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                              error:&error];

  NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:url
                                                  options:0
                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [url length])];
  if (match) {
    NSRange videoIDRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
    NSString *videoId = [url substringWithRange:videoIDRange];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html>\
                      <html>\
                      <head>\
                      <style type='text/css' media='screen'>\
                      body, p{\
                      margin: 0px;\
                      }\
                      #player {\
                      width: 100%%;\
                      }\
                      </style>\
                      </head>\
                      <body><div id='player'></div>\
                      <script type='text/javascript'>\
                      var tag = document.createElement('script');\
                      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';\
                      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];\
                      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);\
                      \
                      var player;\
                      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {\
                      player = new YT.Player('player', {\
                      height: '390',\
                      width: '640',\
                      videoId: '%@',\
                      events: {\
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady,\
                      }\
                      });\
                      }\
                      \
                      function onPlayerReady(event) {\
                      event.target.playVideo();\
                      }\
                      \
                      </script>\
                      </body>\
                      </html>", videoId];
    return html;
  }


  return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this library meets your goals and is easy to use test [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser), 
I hope it will be useful!