# How to play YouTube video without leaving app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, youtube

Is it possible to play YouTube video without leaving app on iOS 7?

I tried [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) but it does not work on iOS 7.

Comment: hecyoutubeParse i think is good which pares the youtube url in suportable format and after parsing you can pass the parsed url to play video or u may follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914360/force-youtube-video-from-uiview-to-play/20920680#20920680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play YouTube video you have to extract the youtube URL from the youtube videoID. there are lots of API available that extract this

[XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit)

[HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser)

Another way to play youtube videos is **WebView**.

But you should not go for this because using this your application will be rejected.

The best way to play youtube videos is the **Webview**

Comment: do you mean using Webview will be rejected? or using XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer / HCYoutubeParser will be rejected?

Comment: No using  XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer / HCYoutubeParser there will be rejected depend on your luck