# Youtube url not playing in MPMovieplayerController fixed frame

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m parsing a json feed containg you tube feeds where i m trying the play the youtube in a fixed frame .when i click the button i getting black background could u guys help me out below is the code

```
-(void)watchClip:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"hello how should this be:%@",URL);
 NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[URL   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];  
moviePlayerController.view.frame=CGRectMake(28,15,250,130);  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:moviePlayerController];  
   //moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  

  [v addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

[moviePlayerController play];  

 }
```

Comment: Are you running in the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

`MPMoviePlayerController` can't play YouTube videos. Use a `UIWebView` instead.

[Play YouTube videos with MPMoviePlayerController instead of UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview)

Here's a [good tutorial](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application) on how to play youtube videos in a fixed frame. Note that if you're running in the simulator it won't work.

Comment: This was true as of iOS 5. It may or may not be true now; feel free to try it and report back so that this question may be appropriately answered.