# play youtube video in iphone app in ios version below 5.1.1?

Tags: iphone, webview, youtube

I want to play a youTube video using youtube video url.

I succeed in playing a video in iOS version 5.1.1 but the video does not played in iOS version 5.0.1 and 4.0 or below. I am using webview to play video.

Comment: I am using shokwave-flash for playing youtube video..

Comment: Flash doesn't work on iOS, you know that.

Comment: but it's work in ios 5.1.1.Any general framework is available for working in all version?

Comment: Have you seen other threads ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview

Comment: My requirement is playing video in UIWebView

Comment: Can you post some sample code for the shockwave code your using?

Comment: My embed code is NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: transparent;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for IOS below 5 you need to use iframe :

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<iframe id=\"yt\"    class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"280\" height=\"186\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx\" frameborder=\"0\">";
and for ios 5 above we can use embed :  
   NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
    <body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx?autoplay=1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
```

Note: In IOS 6 i found out that url works only if we pass youtube url as : http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxx?autoplay=1

Hope this works out.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it looks like you are using the wrong embed code, youtube embeds now look like

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Cw2RzvK13F4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As mentioned before flash won't play on the iPhone, so it needs to use the HTML5 version, unfortunately I don't think 100% of youtube videos have been converted, but most should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your using the proper URL format for embedded videos. They changed it somewhat recently.

[Youtube Embedded Players and Player Parameters - YouTube - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

It looks like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which works well in all previous version of iOS 5.Just give a try with this code. I am sure this is going to fix your problem.

```
// Over here Just replace this url with your one's.
NSString *pdfString = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe39vPFabuA";

NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>\n"
"<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 320\"/></head>\n"
"<body style=\"background:FFF;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">\n"
"<div><object width=\"320\" height=\"416\">\n"
"<param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param>\n"
"<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>\n"
"<embed src=\"%@\"\n"
"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"320\" height=\"416\"></embed>\n"
"</object></div></body></html>\n";

[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,[pdfString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]],[pdfString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]] baseURL:nil];
```

Also, **make sure to test the code in Device only**. Testing on Simulator won't play the Video.