# MPMoviePlayerController error _itemFailedToPlayToEnd while playing youtube video iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've seen this mentioned a few places around the web but have yet to find answer anywhere.

I am using [ALMovieplayercontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/almovieplayercontroller) library. Everything works fine but when i am trying to play Youtube video it gives me error.

**_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}**

**EDIT**

```
- (void)setContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL {

    self.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [super setContentURL:contentURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ALMoviePlayerContentURLDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [self play];
}
```

**Here is my code**

```
ALMoviePlayerControls *movieControls = [[ALMoviePlayerControls alloc] initWithMoviePlayer:self.moviePlayer style:ALMoviePlayerControlsStyleDefault];
//[movieControls setAdjustsFullscreenImage:NO];
[movieControls setBarColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:195/255.0 green:29/255.0 blue:29/255.0 alpha:0.5]];
[movieControls setTimeRemainingDecrements:YES];

//assign controls
[self.moviePlayer setControls:movieControls];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

//THEN set contentURL
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaosmAGx8NM"]];
```

I am not able to find the solution for this.

Please Help.

Comment: Do you solve this trouble?

Comment: @Sk0prion i have answered my question

Comment: @Sunnyshah please accept your own answer to close this question.

Comment: http://cdn.metacafe.com/videos/11419000/11419883/11419883.m3u8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes after so much researching i found to the following soluction.

**MPMoviePlayerController directly will not play the youtube videos.** you have to extract the video URL and set video URL to MPMoviePlayerController. after this video will be played.

There are lots of API available that gives the extracted video URL.

Some of them are below

[XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit)

[HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser)

**But using this API your application might be rejected**. you should have to use on your risk.

Best way to play youtube videos is the WebView.

Answer (score 3):

Ok!!! the problem is that the player doesn't know what you are trying to play,

1. you can try to change the name to x.mp4
2. you can debug the project and see that the path and the file you are trying to play exists.

Comment: We are not talking to play local video. Here we wants to play the YouTube Videos.

Comment: I understand... sorry I had the same error so maybe my answer will help to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken `ALMovieplayercontroller` is an extension of `MPMoviePlayerController`.
So try setting the source type of the player to stream.

```
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Comment: Can u give an example url you trying to set?

Comment: Please check the updated question the URL that i am using is from youtube

Comment: Ok, i see you are trying to load a regular youtube url. unfortunately, that will not work on ios. You can see alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview. hope that helps :)