# _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: { kind = 1; new = 2; old = 0; }

Tags: objective-c, ios7

my video not play

```
 // _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: 
    {
       kind = 1;
       new = 2;
       old = 0;
    }
```

my url is

```
http://leuipe.fr.feedportal.com/c/3265/f/43169/s/2f1abb6/sc/35/l/0Lvideo0Blequipe0Bfr0Cvideo0Cd3b6e1d4cccs0Bhtml/story.htm
```

my code is

```
 movieURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[_dic valueForKey:kRssLink]];
 NSLog(@"%@",movieURL);
 player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

[player setContentURL:movieURL];
[player.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 100, 320, 476)];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

[player play];
```

Comment: what was the problem in my code ... please tell me .... i used first time because i am new in ios. so please dont give me an -ve mark

Comment: `.../story.htm` doesnt look like a video url.

Comment: this page has an video ... when this link run in browser its play the video

Comment: @MAC113 more explanation will be helpful. If a video is not playing there might be several problems. Can you tell exactly what is going on (what is happening when you try to play the vid)? did you test for nil objects passed to the player ?

Comment: if opened in a browser an then playing a video, there is some forwarding or loading involved which will only then fetch the real video url... see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592906/mpmovieplayercontroller-error-itemfailedtoplaytoend-while-playing-youtube-video

Comment: my url is same like an youtube video link ....when i try to play video its display in log like _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: 
    {
       kind = 1;
       new = 2;
       old = 0;
    }

Comment: @property(strong,nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same problem,

```
    _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

But I got it fixed , there was no file located on the given URL. So make sure there is a file at the given URL.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I checked with NSFileManager and see that the file really didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue when using the following to generate the URL for my MPMoviePlayerController

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videoURL];
```

I fixed it by using:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.videoURL];
```

Comment: thanks this solve it for me. Playing local video with  MPMoviePlayerController

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, viewed a lot of topics and haven't found working solution. My app stores movie files on cloud storage (Parse, Amazon S3) and plays them with MPMoviePlayerController.

Reason of such behavior is next: MPMoviePlayerController doesn't want play any file without extension. So adding .mov extension to file names fixed issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with "file.mp4"
None of this answers resolved my problem.
I resolved it by exporting the file in quicktime:

1. Open mp4 on Quicktime :)
2. Go to menu: File -> Export -> iPad,iphone, ipod,...
3. Select the proper format to your needs.

I finished with a m4v file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these properties, I solve problem with the same error message by add these two properties.

```
[player setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](http://engineering.azukisoft.com/weird-_itemfailedtoplaytoend-error-when-playing-mp4-or-mov-in-mpmovieplayercontroller/). I found after I resized the video to smaller size (from 2048 x 1536 to 1024 x 768). It could be played on iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

This may be problem in video format also. Please check the video format is either H.264 or AVC coding. If your video format is H.264, then there are certain limitations. Please check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem and figured out that the video's aspect ratio causes the error. Basically, a video with a certain aspect ratio will work on some devices and won't on the rest:

Device - Video Aspect Ratio

- iPad - 4:3
- iPhone 4-inch - 16:9
- iPhone 3.5-inch - 3:2

Hope this helps.