# check for "_itemFailedToPlayToEnd" in MPmoviePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I'm wordering how I can check for the error-code **"_itemFailedToPlayToEnd"** which is going to be logged to the console. Is there any way to get it as a notification to work with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592906/mpmovieplayercontroller-error-itemfailedtoplaytoend-while-playing-youtube-video and https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView/issues/75